# cfdisk quits with a fatal error in regards to the partition table

Tags: hard-drive, partition, linux

fresh install. 'cfdisk /dev/sda' gives the following output:

"FATAL ERROR: Bad primary partition 2: Partition ends in the final partial cylinder"

what could be the reason for this to happen and what might be the solution?

this is the output of 'fdisk -ucl /dev/sda':

```
Disk /dev/sda: 61.5 GB, 61492838400 bytes 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7476 cylinders, total 120103200 sectors Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disk identifier: 0x00030933

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048     3905535     1951744   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda2   *     3905536     5859327      976896   83  Linux
/dev/sda3         5859328   120102911    57121792   83  Linux
```

Comment: Does the machine boot properly?

Comment: yes, it does...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known `cfdisk` bug, already fixed by some reports.  Partitions haven't needed to be aligned to track boundaries for almost two decades, if indeed ever at all; and most modern partition table utilities don't perform such alignment.  (Microsoft stopped doing it in its utilities, to much fanfare, several years ago.)

But `cfdisk` was checking that they were track-aligned anyway, and complaining (with a fatal error that need not have been fatal) if they weren't.  `cfdisk` clearly wasn't what your installation program used to partition the disc.  Partition tables created with tools that have dropped this nonsense track-alignment idea will of course give `cfdisk` cause for complaint, and that's what has clearly happened here.

**Local fix:** Don't use `cfdisk`.  Use `gparted` or `parted` or some such.  ([As Rod Smith explains](http://rodsbooks.com./gdisk/whygdisk.html), they don't share a common codebase with the `fdisk` family, and so won't share this bug.)  Or bite the bullet and use [GPT fdisk](http://rodsbooks.com./gdisk/) to switch to the EFI partition table format, which has none of this cylinders/heads/sectors residue at all.

**Temporary and service fix:** Get the fixed `cfdisk` from your operating system vendor.

### Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2011). [*The gen on disc partition alignment.*](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/disc-partition-alignment.html).  Frequently Given Answers.